# How to write trigger to generate sequence number for repeated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to generate sequence number for repeated value in a SQL Server table.

Here's my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_all_purple_flag_level](
[Sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Score] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Disability_Level] [varchar](50) NULL,
[visited_count] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Date] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

If `id` has repeated numbers, I need `visited_count` to be a sequence number (1, 2, 3...)

I tried this code

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   RIGHT('0'+ CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By id Order By id)) as varchar(2)), 2) as duplicate_id
FROM 
   tbl_all_purple_flag_level
```

It works fine but I don't know how to do in trigger. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: what RDBMS is this ??

Comment: You probably want `Order By Sno` and not `Order By id` in your last SQL statement.

Comment: tell me how to writer for this...

Comment: I think you want visited_count to increase if the id is the same? So the first record with id='a' has visited_count = 1 and the second record with id='a' has visited_count = 2. And you want to accomplish this with a trigger, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_After_Update_Inser
ON [dbo].[tbl_all_purple_flag_level]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH Updateable
AS
 (
  SELECT [Sno], id,  [visited_count],
        RIGHT('0'+ CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By id Order By id, [Date] DESC)) as varchar(2)), 2) as duplicate_id
  FROM tbl_all_purple_flag_level 
 )
 UPDATE Updateable
  SET [visited_count] =  duplicate_id
END
```

One thing I would like to point out, SQL Server has  Data types to store almost all kinds of data, I can see you are saving Dates in Varchar data type and IDs and Score all in varchar data type, Sql Server has `Date` data type to store date values. why would you use varchar for all the columns dont know but I think you should consider using appropriate data types for your column instead of using VARCHAR for everything.

Comment: I shudder at the though of someone using varchar to store dates! A dat integrity problem just wating to happen.

Comment: @HLGEM tell me about it. any string can end up in that column, knowing some poeple , most probably you will end up having data like `Today` or even `2day` :)